# Rescaling and Shifting algebraically independent set.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I think it is true but I just want to make sure. Let $A$ and $B$ be two algebraically independent subsets  over $\mathbb  Q$  such that $A\cup B$ is algebraically independent. So,

**1**. $q+ A$ is algebraically independent for every $q\in\mathbb Q\setminus\{0\}.$

**2**. Let $C=\{q c+p\colon \ b\in B\ \&\ p,q\in\mathbb Q\setminus\{0\}\}.$ Then $C$ is algebraically independent. In addition, $A\cup C$ is algebraically independent.

Then, **1** and **2** are true. Does that correct? Any help will be appreciated  greatly.

Comment: You meant $qb+p$ ? Algebraically independent means $f(a,c)\ne 0$ for all $f\ne 0 \in \Bbb{Q}[x,y]$, right ? Letting $F(x,y) = f(x,(y-p)/q)$...

Comment: reuns, but this would show $A\cup B$ is algebraically independent., which is not.  Is that right?